# Update Python3 to new installed version on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, python3, version

Tried searching with several strategies but am not finding an effective answer. I just installed Python-3.11.5 to a directory under my "home" directory. When I am in Terminal and type

```
me@mine:~/Python-3.11.5$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

I see no update of the default version number and attempting to use programs that depend on Python v3.7 or above fail. But I have not yet found the correct parameter to alter to get the new version recognized, despite it's presence if I invoke it by minor version directly

```
me@mine:~/Python-3.11.5$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jun 29 2022, 11:45:57) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()

me@mine:~/Python-3.11.5$ python3.11
Python 3.11.5 (main, Aug 27 2023, 13:48:30) [GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

So how can I change the default for `python3` to be 3.11? At the moment this is what aI get with `whereis`:

```
whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.6-config /usr/bin/python3.6m-config /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python3.8 /etc/python3.6 /etc/python3 /etc/python3.5 /usr/local/bin/python3.11 /usr/local/bin/python3.11-config /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.11 /usr/include/python3.6 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

So the system can "see" `/usr/local/bin/python3.11`

EDIT:
So here's what I found as a means of changing the location that the system will use when `python3` is invoked at a Terminal session:

```
me@mine:~/Python-3.11.5$ alias python3=/usr/local/bin/python3.11
```

I don't think the effect is local to the current directory. However, it doesn't change where the outside program attempts to find a python3+ binary. So looking at the PATH I see:

```
david@davids:~$ echo $PATH
/home/david/anaconda3/bin:/home/david/bin:/home/david/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

So thinking that the items in `/home/david/anaconda3/bin` might be being found ...

```
david@davids:~$ ls /home/david/anaconda3/bin
ls: cannot access '/home/david/anaconda3/bin': No such file or directory
```

Still puzzled.

Comment: Not sure if this is the only way but you can find the location where `python-3.11` was installed (`which python3.11`, [etc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262063/how-to-find-python-installation-directory-on-ubuntu)). And then set an alias for that installation in `.bashrc`.

Comment: OK. But I don't think that answers the question of how to get the link located at `/usr/bin/python3` to be pointing at my newly compiled Python-3.11.5

Comment: Be *very* careful updating python versions - it can break the package manager and other tools. I believe (and double check!) that virtualenv is the right way to deal with the issue, or explicitly calling the python binary

Comment: Have never heard of “virtualenv”. Do you have a link?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html (virtualenv docs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type in `python3` in your terminal the shell will try to look up a binary with that name in directories specified in the `${PATH}` variable.  The shell will look up the **exact** name.  In your case the first hit for `python3` seems to be `/usr/bin/python3`, i.e. system Python.  To access your local Python as `python3` you'll need to add a new symlink that will be prioritized (due to `/usr/local/bin/` being before `/usr/bin/` in your `${PATH}`):

```
sudo ln -s python3.11 /usr/local/bin/python3
```

You could also change the system symlink and override `/usr/bin/python3` but that's likely to get reverted on system Python updates and cause issues with any system (apt) installed Python libraries.  I would stay away but if you really want to do this you can run:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/python3.11 /usr/bin/python3
```

As for your `alias` attempt.

> I don't think the effect is local to the current directory.

It is not, however aliases don't get propagated to subprocesses so your scripts won't see them.  Adding a `python3` symlink pointing to the binary you want to the `${PATH}` used by your scripts is the correct way to set your local Python as the default one.

To go the [virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) route you could also do:

```
python3.11 -m venv myvenv
```

And then run `source myvenv/bin/activate` in your shell to set up the `${PATH}` in a way that it sees the venv Python binary as `python` (and `python3` and `python3.11` too).  For individual projects virtualenvs are a great way to isolate dependencies and always use a consistent version of the Python binary.

Comment: Upvoting and will accept if it succeeds. I tried to `mv` the use/bin/python3.6 directory out but that seemed to make matters worse, so I reverted the name change.

Comment: I'd recommend not altering the system Python installation as it usually only causes issues.  For a more per-project/localized approach I'd recommend using a virtualenv.

Comment: Restored the symlink for python3.6 and then added teh symlink in your first suggestion and the external program requiring python >= 3.7 is running wihtout complaint.